# In python beyond 'exec string' is there a way to 'import' using the db as a filesystem

Tags: python

Although it does not seem possible, I wanted to put this out there to see if others had some innovative solutions to 'dynamically loading and executing code in python'

So if one saved code in a database, one could read it and 'exec it', however if one wanted to use it in a similar fashion to the filesystem, one would need to

1. 'save and load the compiled .pyc'
2. create an 'import dbimp' ala 'import imp' etc.

any pointers? ideas? thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/): New Import Hooks, for details on how to hook the importer.

Python 3.1 has an [importlib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/importlib.html), designed to make hooking the importer a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement customized import hooks and register them into `sys.meta_path`. See [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) for the details.